# How to select data from mysql with condition of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables: **users** and **sub_list**.

Table users contain username and table sub_list contains username, subscribed_user.

```
**table users**
*username:* john,harris,samantha,peter,joe,max

**table sub_list**
*username:* harris, harris, peter 
*subscribed_user:* samantha, john, joe
```

Let's say my name is harris...

Now I want query to select a random user from table `users` limited by 1, where `harris` is not subscribed to that user in table `subscribed_user`.

So I don't want to get results like: `samantha` and `john` because I've already subscribed to them.

This code below doesn't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.username='harris' NOT IN (
   SELECT username
   FROM sub_list)
ORDER BY RAND() DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your table structure (maybe with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)), because from your explanation I can't really make sense of how it is set up. A relational database consists of tables, which contain rows. You posted basically two lists and didn't explain their relationship. :) If you don't like to build a fiddle, maybe try "drawing" your database in ASCII within a code block or something.

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE username NOT IN (
   SELECT username
   FROM sub_list
   WHERE username='harris')
ORDER BY RAND() DESC
LIMIT 1´

Comment: I hope this could help you. Table structure [link](http://i.imgur.com/1Pn5tiX.png)